# How do GET calls work in Angular/Express?

Tags: angularjs, http, express, mean-stack

my group is building a MEAN stack application, and I'm currently having trouble with GET calls.

so if there is some code in the server.js

```
app.get('/confirm-login', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.session.username)
});
```

I thought I could retrieve that in angular using

```
$http({method: 'GET',  url: '/confirm-login'})
.then(function successCallback(user) {
      if (user) {
            $rootScope.user = user;
            console.log(user);
        }
}, function errorCallback(response) {    
});
```

But that returns my index file instead. Console prints out the contents of the index file.

Apparently, "When you request a URL which cannot be found, sometimes the default 404 contents will be returned, which is the index.html page in this case."

What am I doing wrong with GET calls, or more importantly how do I do this right?

HERE IS THE FULL SERVER CODE:
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5371

Comment: Console.log your server please: app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  console.log.....
});

Comment: I added app.get('*', function(req, res) { console.log("GET HERE")}); and browsed through all the website functions. Nothing happened. We've tested that POST works but never for GET.  Here's the full server code if it helps: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5371

Comment: Sounds like you might have a redirect for HTML5 mode or otherwise that's redirecting the get request to the index.html  Nothing is wrong with your $http call but $http.get('/confirm-login') would work fine as well.

Comment: I think you may be right. It is using HTML5mode, see here: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5372

Comment: The problem is if I remove that line, all routing stops. I'm not sure why because I wasn't the one who set it up, and he's not being very responsive. Am I better off with trying with HTML5 mode or removing it and trying to fix the routing?

Comment: The redirect should be setup in a way that any requests to paths not handled by other .get requests and don't resolve to actual template files gets redirected to the index.html so angular routing can handle the url from there to load the appropriate state on the client side.  Typically good if your API is separated from your client code. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode